# Cloning embedded document only works if value is changed

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I have a Mongo database to which I am connected through the following document classes in Symfony, using Doctrine ODM (I am only showing the relevant properties).

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 * @MongoDB\InheritanceType("COLLECTION_PER_CLASS")
 */
class Feature {
    /** @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="FeatureProperties") */
    protected $properties;
}

/** @MongoDB\Document */
class City extends Feature {}

/** @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument */
class FeatureProperties {
    /** @MongoDB\String */
    protected $name;
}
```

I am trying to clone a `City` in my controller, including its `properties`, essentially its `properties.name`.

To do this, I get the city using QueryBuilder and call it `$city_origin`.
Then, here's how I clone it:

```
$new_city = clone $city_origin;
$city_name = $city_origin->getProperties()->getName();
// $city_name .= ' ';
$documentManager->detach($city_origin);
$new_city->setId('_' . $city_origin->getId());
$new_city->getProperties()->setName($city_name);
$documentManager->persist($new_city);
$documentManager->flush();
```

The new document is created, but `properties` and `properties.name` do not exist.
Now the strange thing is, if I uncomment the line where I modify the `$city_name`, then the `properties.name` is created with the modified value.
If instead of fetching the `$city_name` from `$city_origin` I input its value manually (as a string), the attribute is not created either. If I give the name of another `City` in my collection, there is no issue.

Ideally, I would like to clone the entire document with its embedded documents: how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you clone a object, you get a copy of this object whit the same reference of the embedded object.

When you do :

```
$documentManager->detach($city_origin);
```

Doctrine will detach all the object related to $city_origin because of your entity definition :

```
cascade=DETACH or cascade=ALL
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities

You need to define the clone function in the city class and clone all the object you need.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php